# script and Console log return nothing while running it via nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have some trouble trying to get this script working!

In my route, I have these lines of code:

```
  .state('app.subcats', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/subcat/:idcat',
    views: {
      'menuContent@app': {
        templateUrl: 'client/templates/shop/subcat.html',
        controller: 'SubcatsCtrl as vm' 
      }
    }
  })
```

Here is the script subcat.js:

```
import { _meteorAngular } from 'meteor/angular';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

angular
    .module('salephone')
    .controller('SubcatsCtrl', SubcatsCtrl);

function SubcatsCtrl (
                    $scope,
                    $stateParams,
                    $state,
                    $reactive,
                    $rootScope,
                    $ionicLoading,
                    $ionicHistory,
                    $ionicViewSwitcher,
                    $timeout
                  ){
  $reactive(this).attach($scope);
  console.log("test");
  var self = this;
  this.subcats = [];
  this.contentLoaded = false;
  self.noPosts = "";

  if( window.localStorage.getItem('subcats') ){
    this.productss = JSON.parse( window.localStorage.getItem('subcats') );
  }

  //Variables for infinite scroll.
  self.loaded = 100;
  self.limit = self.loaded;

  console.log("test 1");

  this.getSubcat = function(){

    //Load products on scroll.
    this.subscribe('SubcatMain', () => [ $stateParams.idcat, self.loaded ], {
      onReady: function() {
        //Get count of all Products in server.
        //Method is located at tapshop/lib/methods/app_methods.js
        Meteor.call('allSubcats', $stateParams.idcat, function(err, count) {
            self.allsubcats = count;
          self.limit = self.loaded;

          self.subcats = Products.find({
            catLinkID : $stateParams.idcat,
            listingsCount: { $gt: 0 }
          },{
            sort: {
              productOffersCount: -1,
              listingsCount: -1,
              name: 1
            },
            limit: self.limit
          }).fetch();

          window.localStorage.setItem('subcats', JSON.stringify(self.subcats) );

          self.contentLoaded = true;
          self.noPosts = 'No posts available.';

          $ionicLoading.hide();
          return;        
        });
      },
      onStop: function(err){
        console.log("test 2");
        if(err){
          self.contentLoaded = true;
          self.noPosts = "No internet connection.";
          console.log(JSON.stringify(err)); // <- nothing here
          return;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  this.getSubcat();

  ...
```

When I launch the script, I get only:

```
No internet connection.
```

Nothing about the error message! And, I see no place in which I made an error!

Could someone give me any idea of the problem, please?

I am working on IONIC V1 + METEOR.

Notice that nothing returned from the database as well!

Comment: Many thing to note: Do not use Json.stringify for error output, because the property message of an error is not readable by JSON.stringify(). just do console.error(err).

Why do you use this.getSubcat(); ? Maybe just do getSubcat();

Comment: Thank's for the answer but do not solve the problem, still same thing.

Comment: Where do You see the result 'no internet...' in which console ? Bécasse if You fall there, that us because there are an error but maybe You do not watch thé good console (server side or in client side)

Comment: I see the error inside the browser so client side ! in the server side there nothing.